# EJB Container initialization error, could not invoke defineClass

Tags: jakarta-ee, kotlin, glassfish

My glassfish throws an exception when I try to run.

> [2018-02-22T17:07:04.135+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=46
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1519315624135] [levelValue: 1000] [[   Exception while loading the app : EJB
>   Container initialization error java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not
>   invoke defineClass!

I uploaded the server log here: https://pastebin.com/cB0EgG4Y

UserDao

```
@Stateless
class UserDao : Abstract<User>() {
    override fun getEntityClass(): Class<User> {
        return User::class.java
    }
}
```

Abstract Dao

```
@Stateless
abstract class Abstract<T : Model> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "kwetter")
    private lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

    abstract fun getEntityClass(): Class<T>

    fun find(id: Int): T {
        return entityManager.find(getEntityClass(), id)
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Stateless
class UserService {
    @Inject private var userDao: UserDao? = null

    fun find(id: Int): User {
        return userDao!!.find(id)
    }
}
```

API endpoint

```
@Stateless
@Named
@Path("/users")
class Users {
    @Inject private var userService: UserService? = null

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    fun single(@PathParam("id") id: Int): User {
        return userService!!.find(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, all classes are implicitly `final` by default, hence this error in your logs:

> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)

Mark your classes as open if you want to extend them:

> *The open annotation on a class is the opposite of Java's final: it allows others to inherit from this class. By default, all classes in
>   Kotlin are final, which corresponds to Effective Java, Item 17: Design
>   and document for inheritance or else prohibit it.*

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the *all-open-compiler-plugins* : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin

> Kotlin has classes and their members final by default, which makes it
>   inconvenient to use frameworks and libraries such as Spring AOP that
>   require classes to be open. The all-open compiler plugin adapts Kotlin
>   to the requirements of those frameworks and makes classes annotated
>   with a specific annotation and their members open without the explicit
>   open keyword

See also : https://dzone.com/articles/the-state-of-kotlin-for-jakarta-eemicroprofile-tra